# How will quantum computing change programming?

Tags: programming-languages, algorithms

How is programming a quantum algorithm different? What would a C like language look like if it was designed for qubits? Would types change?

Comment: Note: Im not sure if this is a valid question. Sorry if it is not.

Comment: I think it is. Then again, I don't really know the rules of this site very well. And I don't really have a great answer to this question, but I know of this algorithm that could be used to factor integers much more efficiently: http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0380

Comment: I think though this topic is still at scientific research, the basics of an hypothetical quantum computer are AFAIK well known, so the question should be answerable by a domain expert (which I am not). So I vote *not* to close it.

Answer (score 17):

When I looked into this some time ago, it was clear that quantum algorithms, while not particularly fast, permit exponentially massive parallelism.
So they will shine in cases involving search in spaces that are not practical with sequential hardware, even massively parallel sequential hardware.

One property of quantum algorithms is that they have to be *reversible*.
Any given algorithm can be translated into one that is reversible, by adding to it enough record-keeping to allow it to be run backward.

Another property is that getting an answer out of a quantum algorithm is a hit-and-miss affair, because what you get at the end of a computation is multiple answers, each with its own probability. It needs to be run in such a way that the answer you want has high probability.
This may involve running the algorithm forward and backward multiple times.

Check out [*Grover's Search Algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm).

---

INSERTED to show the fundamental operation of Grover's algorithm. Suppose there is a search problem. The possible answers are 0, 1, 2, and 3, but the *right* answer is 2. So the quantum computer is put in a superposition of all four states, and it goes through a sequence of steps to see which one is correct, and inverts its amplitude, like the black dots and arrows below:

[image]

You can see that arrow 2 has been inverted inside the machine, but there's no way to tell that outside, because only probabilities are visible outside, which are amplitudes *squared*, and when squared they are all equal.

However, the amplitudes have a mean, indicated by the red line, and the computer can be made to go through a sequence of steps that *inverts each amplitude about the mean*.
When that is done, the amplitudes, and the probabilities, transfer to state 2, the *right answer* !
So if the machine is observed, state 2 shines forth.

It's not quite this simple. Generally it takes multiple cycles of the machine, forward and backward, inverting at the end of each cycle, to maximize the probability of the right answer. Also, one must take care not to do it any more than that number of times, because it can just as easily reverse itself.

So why do they say quantum computers are so *fast*?
Because every time you double the number of qubits, you square the parallelism, but you don't square the length of time, so eventually it wins.

Isn't that fun?

---

I was personally interested in how this could be applied to verification of software correctness.
Now we test software by throwing a bunch of test inputs at it and (to be overly simple) seeing if it hits an Assert.
In a quantum computer it might be possible to run it in parallel against a much denser set of inputs and see if any of those cases hit an Assert.

Like if the input to the algorithm were 128 bytes, or 1024 bits, there are 2^1024 or 10^308 possible different inputs. There is no way to test that many inputs on a conventional computer, but a quantum computer could try them all in parallel.

Comment: Checking out Grover's Search Algorithm... OH GOD! I wasn't ready for that!

Comment: @Philip: I know the math is pretty off-putting, but the key idea is the rotation about the mean, which has the effect of transferring probability to the answer state. Then you run back to the beginning and run forward and do it again, a certain number of times. Then if you do the observation, you've maximized the probability of seeing the answer state.

Comment: You see, it's really not so bad when you say it like that. I guess I'm not familiar with the notation they're using or quantum circuits. The page on quantum algorithms is likewise intimidating. I believe that [Qubit](http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) is the place to start. (Simple wikipedia has a page on [Quantum computers](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer), but it could use some work)

Comment: @Philip: Suppose you have a 1024-entry table, so it takes 10 bits to index it. You have a 10-(qu)bit register, and it has 1024 possible states. OK, so you create a universe in which the register is 0, another in which it is 1, up to 1024 parallel universes. Then the quantum "instructions" operate on all of these in parallel. Each universe has an "amplitude vector", whose magnitude is its probability, but it also has a direction, and those are being manipulated. Since the collection of 1024 vectors has a non-zero average vector, the rotation makes one bigger, the rest smaller.

Comment: I am a reformed physicist and I downvoted this answer because it is misleading. 1) quantum algorithms frequently _are_ particularly (asymptotically) fast - Grover's search algorithm runs in O(sqrt(n)) whereas the best a classical computer can do is O(n). If quantum computers were not asymptotically faster they would not be very interesting. The hardware may be slow right now but that's not the algorithms' fault!

Comment: 2) it's not the case the quantum algorithms are non-deterministic, as you imply. Measuring the system at an arbitrary point in time will give you a non-deterministic answer, but at the end of the program you'll get a definite answer. The essence of quantum algorithms is the art of (deterministically) manipulating the system so that you'll (deterministically) get the right answer, 100% of the time. Again, existing hardware implementations of quantum computers don't achieve 100% reliability right now but that's why it's an area of active research

Comment: 3) your explanation about quantum computers running in parallel is controversial in the physics community. There's an interpretation of quantum mechanics, the _Many Worlds_ interpretation, under which it could be said that quantum computers are parallel computers in some sense, but it's not universally accepted. The programs one runs in a quantum computer are decidedly sequential, in that they consist of a number of transformations which are applied to the system one after another.

Comment: 4) Quantum algorithms are reversible, but that's a consequence of a stronger property called unitarity. Unitary transformations are invertible but not all invertible transformations are unitary. It is not the case that you can take a classical algorithm, make it reversible by adding journaling, and expect it to make sense as a quantum algorithm. Sorry to be so nit-picky in my comments. I hope you will take them in the spirit with which they were intended - one of learning and knowledge-sharing

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson: Thanks for your feedback. I was not aware of point 4, that reversible does not imply unitary. About point 3, I'm not aware of how many-worlds is not good enough for understanding computation. On 2, I didn't intend to imply non-determinism of each state's evolution, but getting the P of the answer up to 1 was not easy for me. On 1, I was a little breezy (for the breezy readers) but I think I said what you said in a different way. Regardless, thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

> What would a C like language look like if it was designed for qubits? Would types change?

It would be so drastically different as to be incomprehensible as C.

The main issue (as I understand it) is that quantum computing does not work in a nice imperative manner 'do this, then that, then this other thing'. Trying to force C's ability to do that into the 'processor' of quantum computer will be if not impossible, wildly inefficient.

Programming algorithms for quantum computers (again, as I understand them) tend to be closer to functional programming style map/reduce, since quantum computing allows all of the candidates in the 'reduce' part to exist concurrently and "fall out" of the computer when observed.

Note that there are some existing algorithms for quantum computers, even though the devices don't exist to run them. [Simon's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon%27s_algorithm) for example.

Comment: ELI5 for a quantum algorithm would be great.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the most effective possible use of a quantum computer, one needs to be able to deal with inputs and outputs that are states of a quantum register, for which there is really no classical analogue. Speaking from some years of experience in the field of quantum information, I must warn you that no one really has a good intuition for this beyond the abstract mathematics of C* algebras, and I'm told that even this intuition turns out to be inadequate if you start wondering about relativity theory.

The class of problems that are efficiently solvable on a quantum computer is known as BQP, for Bounded Quantum Polynomial. This is the quantum version of BPP, and you can find more information in this paper: http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bqpph.pdf

I was told just last night by a quantum algorithms researcher that there is a very important problem that is BQP-complete: solving a linear system of N equations. Classically, this is solvable in O(N) steps with Gaussian elimination. The Harrow-Hassidim-Lloyd algorithm (http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171) solves it in polylog(N), provided you are willing to accept an answer that has the solution encoded as a quantum state. If you want to make full use of a quantum computer, it therefore seems necessary for you to have a type corresponding to the state of a quantum register.

Though I am a little outside of my particular expertise right now, I would hazard a guess that you would be able to program a quantum computer as long as you had access to a type corresponding to magic states. That's a difficult concept, though, that requires quite some study of the subject.

Be warned that we are a very long time from having a quantum programming language, because we are at a very primitive stage of quantum computing research. Asking for a quantum C right now would be like going to Alan Turing and asking him to design Python. We haven't even got the quantum version of the vacuum tube yet!